# bst Print leaves error

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, binary-search-tree, counter

I should implement a code for printing leaves in a binary tree but I've had some errors and honestly they're recurring quite frequently so I would appreciate explaining how to avoid them once and for all .

```
 public void printLeaves() { 
 int counter = 1;
 printLeaves(overallRoot,counter); } 
 private void printLeaves(IntTreeNode root ,int counter ) {
//System.out.println(counter);
   if (root.data==0) { } else if(root.left==null&&root.right==null){
   if (counter==1){System.out.print( "leaves: ");}
   counter++;
  System.out.print(root.data+" ");}
  else { printLeaves(root.right,counter); 
          printLeaves(root.left,counter);
   }
```

errors in my code involve leaves : getting printed twice (since i never get how and where to implement my counter ) and null pointer exceptions ( because there is some concept I don't anticipate while implementing my code

Answer (score 0):

In the code

```
else { printLeaves(root.right,counter); 
      printLeaves(root.left,counter);
}
```

You don't check if root.right and root.left are not null before calling.